# Plotting a Prometheus counter as number of events in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Say I have a counter counting some errors. The application with the counter can run multiple instances. My understanding is that something like this will give me a graph with errors per second per instance of the application.

```
rate(lookup_errors_total[5m])
```

I find that errors per second makes is it mentally challenging to interpret the graph (perhaps thats just me). Is there any way to plot this as a bar chart in Grafana where each bar represents a number of errors?

Comment: are you looking for something like `num of of the last 24h` or what should the number on that bar chart represent?

Comment: I would like each bar to represent a number of events within some time bucket. So if I have five bars 2, 3, 5, 1, 4 it should be possible to count them and say that during the entire timespan I've had 15 error events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following query:

```
sum(increase(lookup_errors_total[$__range]))
```

`increase` will calculate the absolute increase of events counted (and not calculating down the number of events per second)
`sum` will sum up multimple timelines, so you have a single timeline in the end

`$__range` will be the length of your selected timeline in grafana (e.g. if you selected one day, it will be `24h` (or and equivalent value like  `1d` or `1440m`)